# Print in console list all views, Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, console

I used to use commando, console and write something in the console shows the list of views on the controller.

But I can not remember the command and find it

Something like "po XXX"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
po [[self view] recursiveDescription]
```

show current view UI Hierarchy